# concurrent way to load multiple loadRequest of webView

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad, cocoa

Currently I have about 4 to 5 different webView's which I am trying to load simultaneously, however I have come across the conclusion that only one loadRequest can load at a time. Although I have created custom class for each webview, the loadRequest, doesn't seams to get called, while if there is another loadRequest of a webview is being utilized.

Is there anyway to keep these calls in different Thread's to make it work or utilize in dispatch mechanism? Just trying to figure out if there is an alternative.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use NSUrlConnection to preload the data, no threading

```
    //for EACH url to load
    NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:tweet[@"profile_image_url"]]];
    [NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:request
                                       queue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] // one should ideally use a different queue here to free main thread and ONLY do the imageView.image setting in Main thread
                           completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *error) {
                               if(!error) {
                                   //load webview! with Data maybe!
                               }
                           }];
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you seem to have only 4 or 5 web views, it is not that inefficient to call them on a dispatch queue. If there are 100's of requests, then you need to think of some strategies though.

```
NSArray *myWebSites = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"www.cnn.com",@"www.fox.com",....,nil];

for(url in myWebsites){
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue, ^{
        // get the data from the url.

        // do the display in main queue
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_mainqueue, ^{
            //load the web view;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: no need for threads. NSURLConnections work good on common runloop :) just dont do any synchronous networking

Comment: I am having another issue here. I am sending this object of custom UIWebView class via delegate to another class. Now, I noticed the loadRequest call does makes, but none of the delegates gets called, although I have set the delegates to self. The only time I notice the calls being made if I instantiate the object in the same class. Am I missing something here regarding the loadRequest? thanks.